# Programmatically trigger a click event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have seen some jquery code where it appears that a click event is triggered programmatically like so:

```js
$sortElements.on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).is('a')) {
      e.target.click();
    } else {
      $(this).click();
    }
  }
});
```

Is this a best practice and or is there a better way to do this?

Also, I have read that the jquery short hand for click is deprecated and the correct way is to write:

```
$(elem).on("click", function(){})
```

I don't think it's possible to programmatically trigger a click using this new format however.

Comment: `I have read that the jquery short hand for click is deprecated` this is not true at all.

Comment: There is a similar shorthand for both the `on` and the `trigger` of a click, which may be confusing. You're trying to use the event listener to trigger the event. But as mentioned above, they're both still valid, so you really don't need to change anything.

Comment: `$(this).is('a')` => `this.tagName === 'A'` :|

Comment: It states that this method is deprecated as documented here.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated

Comment: That's jqMigrate, not jQuery itself

Answer (score -4):

Probably the best way to perform the click event with JQuery involved in somewhere is

```
$('#clickme')[0].click()
```

Comment: These seems opinionated.  Why would this be better than `trigger('click')`?

Comment: Because it has the ease of selecting the element via JQuery and the power of performing the action directly in the DOM level.

Comment: getElementById is super easy too

Comment: Bit longer than $('#') to type ;)

Comment: jQuery instantiation *every time* is much longer than you typing a few more characters *once*

Comment: Looks like OP doesn't have that problem and Jquery is his favorite ;)

Comment: I'm not addressing the OP right now, but your answer.  And the point that jQuery instantiation is a **much** more involved process than just using a native method.  While there is an *ease* of use of using jQuery, you should always be aware of the cost.  If you are not familiar with just how much work goes into the object instantiation, I would highly recommend taking some time to review the library and just see what all goes on when one is made.  It's not a simple process by far.

Comment: I'm addressing the OP. I will recommend you to read the question again :)